# How to map REST parameters to complex object?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I want to create a `REST` service with `spring` that takes a bunch of parameters. I'd like these parameters to be mapped automatically into a complex transfer object, like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String content(@RequestParam RestDTO restDTO) {
    Sysout(restDTO); //always null
}

public class RestDTO {
    private boolean param;
    //getter+setter
}
```

But: when I execute a query like `localhost:8080/myapp?param=true` the restDTO param remains `null`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I have to omit the `@RequestParam` for complex objects:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String content(RestDTO restDTO) {
    Sysout(restDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `localhost:8080/myapp?param=true`.

Probably a case where another pair of eyes sees the obvious :)

**EDIT**

Remove `@RequestParam` from method signature, works for me.

Comment: sorry, I of course ment to write `myapp?param`, edited above.

Answer (score 0):

So, I see few problems (if it's not mistyping of course):

1. `localhost:8080/myapp&param=true` "&" isn't correct, you have to use "?" to split params from URL like `localhost:8080/myapp?param=true`.
2. I don't see mapping value in `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` (But if you caught the request you've made correct configuration).